# what is wrong with this python code? very simple code

Tags: python

for some reason this python code doesn't work.
can you please help me?
after asking for input it just prints nothing.

I need this program to print freezing if the temperature is 0 and if above zero print above freezing and if below zero print below freezing.

```
temp = int(input("What is the temperature?"))
if (temp<0):
 print:"Below freezing"
elif (temp>0):
 print:"Above Freezing"
else:
 print:"Freezing"
```

Comment: `print:"Freezing"` is not Python syntax, at least in < 3.6

Comment: Actually, *it is* valid syntax, but I think it is taking it as a type-hint..

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, that's only in Python >=3.6

Comment: @MosesKoledoye well, Python >= 3.5 I think..

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a colon in front of `print()`.

If you're using python 2.x:
    print "Below freezing"

If you're using python 3.x:
    print("Below freezing")